# Take the value of a child element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this structure:

```
<td class=​"prd-var-price">
    ​<div class=​"price-total">​
        <span class=​"price-unit">​€​</span>
        ​<span class=​"price-value">​
            <span class=​"price-value-int">​1.760​</span>
            ​<span data-decimalseparator=​"," class=​"price-value-cent">​,00​</span>​
        </span>
    ​</div>​
</td>​
```

when I write in the console:

> a.getElementsByClassName("prd-var-price")

I would to take the value of *price-value-int* element (1760), I tried with:

> $(a.getElementsByClassName("prd-var-price").getElementsByClassName("price-value-int"));

but this not work.

Comment: `$('.price-value-int').text();`

Comment: $(".prd-var-price").find(".price-value-int").text();

Comment: `$(".prd-var-price").find(".price-value-int").text();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements, if you want only the first one (and in your example - you do) you should use `a.getElementsByClassName("prd-var-price")[0].getElementsByClassName("price-value-int")[0]`

but since you are using jQuery, a simpler approach would be:

```
 $('.prd-var-price .price-value-int');
```

jQuery uses css selector syntax to grab elements, you'll still get an array if more then one of this class structure exists

Answer (score 0):

You might have multiple `td` with same class.

Better to use `parent > child selection` with `find()`

```
$('.prd-var-price').find('.price-value-int').text();
```

In `each()`

```
$('.prd-var-price').each(function(){
   console.log($(this).find('.price-value-int').text());
});
```

```js
$('td.prd-var-price').each(function(key, value){
  console.log($(this).find('.price-unit').text());
  console.log($(this).find('.price-value-int').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
<td class="prd-var-price">
    <div class="price-total">
        <span class="price-unit">€</span>
        <span class="price-value">
            <span class="price-value-int">1.760</span>
            <span data-decimalseparator="," class="price-value-cent">00</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</td>
<td class="prd-var-price">
    <div class="price-total">
        <span class="price-unit">@</span>
        <span class="price-value">
            <span class="price-value-int">2.760</span>
            <span data-decimalseparator="," class="price-value-cent">00</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery `FIND` function to achieve your Goal

```
$(".prd-var-price").find(".price-value-int").text();
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/deyw246s/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Better to use `$('.prd-var-price .price-value-int)` instead of using `$(a.getElementsByClassName("prd-var-price").getElementsByClassName("price-value-int"));`

Answer (score 0):

By using JQuery:

$("tr.prd-var-price").find('div.price-total span.price-value span:first-child").text();